# Mazda 3 over-revs after releasing the clutch pedal on up-shifts, but mechanic says clutch is fine

Tags: clutch, mazda-3

I originally thought I wasn't getting the bite-point right on our new (2nd-hand 2005) Mazda 3, but after paying more attention it's clear that when up-shifting, the engine revs often blip up about 1000 *after* I've totally released the clutch pedal, for a second or so, before dropping back down.

I assumed this meant the clutch was slipping and maybe needed replacing but our mechanic says it's fine, and this is normal on that car. I can't understand how this can happen - once the gear is engaged how can the revs increase so much for a short time *without* it being slip?

Comment: You've ridden with the mechanic and demonstrated this?

Comment: two years later i guess we can ask for an update on how long the clutch lasted

Answer (score 1):

I found [this video of an '04 Mazda 3](http://youtu.be/oIui7cgK3UI) which shows a slipping clutch. The one in the video has really bad slippage. I doubt yours is there yet, but wanted to show you how you can test yours. Basically if, while from around 10-15mph, you can put it into 3rd or 4th and romp on the gas and your rpms go up without the car going faster, your clutch is slipping and is on its way out. If the engine bogs and you slowly increase speed, your clutch is probably doing its job.

Personally, I would go to another mechanic and get a second opinion. There is no way in my mind a standard shift transmission would do this without there being an issue with the clutch.

Comment: The thing is, he said he could see the problem I've mentioned, but that "it's just something Mazdas do" especially when short-shifting. It seemed odd to me too!

Comment: While it is admirable of him to not be seeking work which, in his mind, does not need to be done, I'd seek a second opinion ... especially if you have a friend who knows what they are looking for. Do as I've suggested and see if it slips when you are rolling with the clutch fully engaged. If it slips under those circumstances, the clutch is toast.  I am just not seeing how a clutch can do as you are describing without there being an issue.

Comment: I agree, unless there's a deliberate slip-mechanism (sort of like an anti-stall) but it doesn't seem likely. I'll ask someone else and of course monitor to see if it gets worse.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually normal.The ECU rises the revs to keep up the temp in the cat.Annoying but becoming more standard, esp on petrol engines.